# Time series analysis ARCH($m$) model

Tags: analysis, statistics

Consider a stationary ARCH($m$) model $a_t=\sigma_t\epsilon_t$, where $\sigma^2=\alpha_0+\alpha_1a^2_{t-1}+\cdots+\alpha_ma^2_{t-m}$.

V. Consider an ARCH(2) model. Write down the predictor of $a_{t+2}$, $a^2_{t+2}$ and $\sigma^2_{t+2}$ based on $\{a_t,a_{t-1},\ldots\}$.

- Do I use the l-step ahead forecast formula for $\sigma^2_{h+l}$ which is $\sigma^2_h(l)=\alpha_0+\sum^m_{i=1}\alpha_i\sigma^2_h(l-i)$ where $\sigma^2_h(l-i)=a^2_{h+l-i}$ if $l-i \leq 0$.